# PL/SQL Select and Update statement inside OPEN - FOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have a pl/sql function and I want to select and update table inside open for statement
It looks like this:

table_a

id | status | document_id |

```
create or replace function a(p_document_id in number)
    return sys_refcursor
    is
    result sys_refcursor;
begin
    open result for
        select id
        from table_a t
        where t.document_id = p_document_id;

    update table_a t
    set t.status = 1
    where id in (select id
        from table_a t
        where t.document_id = p_document_id);

    return result;

end;
/
```

But it is not working. Is there some method to do this? thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to open a cursor since you have an ID which - I presume - will give you only one row?

Comment: There would be more than one column

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample table:

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

        ID DOCUMENT_ID     STATUS
---------- ----------- ----------
         1         100          0
```

Function you wrote *compiles*, but doesn't work because functions - normally - don't do DML:

```
SQL> select a(100) from dual;
select a(100) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.A", line 11


SQL>
```

It, though, would work from PL/SQL, e.g.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    l_rc := a(100);
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table_a;

        ID DOCUMENT_ID     STATUS
---------- ----------- ----------
         1         100          1

SQL>
```

---

But, if you want to be able to call the function from PL/SQL, it has to be an autonomous transaction, which also means that you have to commit within:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> create or replace function a(p_document_id in number)
  2      return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4      result sys_refcursor;
  5      pragma autonomous_transaction;             --> this
  6  begin
  7      open result for
  8          select id
  9          from table_a t
 10          where t.document_id = p_document_id;
 11
 12      update table_a t
 13      set t.status = 1
 14      where id in (select id
 15          from table_a t
 16          where t.document_id = p_document_id);
 17
 18      commit;                                     --> this
 19
 20      return result;
 21  end;
 22  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> select a(100) from dual;

A(100)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID
----------
         1


SQL> select * from table_a;

        ID DOCUMENT_ID     STATUS
---------- ----------- ----------
         1         100          1

SQL>
```

This might, or might not be OK. Autonomous transactions can be tricky and we usually use them for logging purposes, so that their commit doesn't affect the main transaction.